# Function search string with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, search

I'm trying to implement a function search with angularjs.
The problem is that the function returns my interest but when I delete the search the function returns all objects in set.
function:

```
$scope.$watch('q', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if (oldValue != null) {
     $http.get('/api/services.json?q=' + newValue)
       .success(function(data) {
         $scope.services = data;
       });
   };
}, true);
```

By being paged this problem is not good for my system.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What should it do? I would say it makes sense to return all objects in your example if you don't have a search value.

Perhaps you want to check for newValue == "" somewhere, or do you want to limit your results?

Comment: The results in search is a service in set, this it is ok! The page in project are paginated, 8 by 8 elements, but when i excludes a demand the function return all elements in a single page without pagination. The function, with newValue == "" this it is cool, dont search. I want that when researched, return my research with elements, if you have the set and when you delete this search does not return all set elements, only those who are on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't use pagination anymore when searching, I think that's your main issue here, not the searching itself.

Combine that with some conditionals inside your $watch to define when you actually want to filter on your search, and you're good to go.

Comment: This paging is for elements that are enabled, paging is that these elements do not pollute the page, in short, the purpose is that the function does not return all elements of the set when the search is cleared.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can prevent returning all elements by  checking for newValue's value in your $watch function. Question remains, what DO you want to show if that happens?